# Replacing "." in Powershell without altering extension

Tags: powershell

Hi I'm using the following Powershell Script to clean up some filenames..

```
get-childitem -recurse -Include *.mp4 | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace(".", " ") }
```

In short, replacing "." with " ".. However this also removes the "." preceding the extension.. Is there way I can exclude the final "." so the extension isn't changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the path, base file name and the extension. Fortunately, the objects returned by `Get-ChildItem` have them available to you.

This *should* work (linebreak for readability)

```
get-childitem -recurse -Include *.mp4 | ForEach-Object {
rename-item $_ -newname $(Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath "$($_.BaseName.Replace(".", " "))$_.Extension)") -WhatIf }
```

Remove `-whatif` once you've confirmed that it's going to do what you want.

Comment: Using Rename-Item you don't need to specify path (it's actually better not to since if the path is different it just throws an error). You could really shorten that whole -NewName thing to `"$($_.BaseName.Replace(".", " "))$_.Extension)"`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I'm using this code: `get-childitem -recurse -Include *.mp4 | ForEach-Object { rename-item $_ -newname "$($_.BaseName.Replace(".", " "))$_.Extension)" }` but I keep getting an error at Cht58 (rename-item).. Am I making a mistake in the syntax?

Comment: Sorry, I had a `)` where I should have had a `+` in there. I would do: `Get-ChildItem -recurse -include *.mp4 | ForEach{ $_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.BaseName.Replace(".", " ")+$_.Extension)" }`